# How to prove that for all non-empty sets A, B, $(A \in \mathscr P(S)$ AND $(B \in \mathscr P(S)$) implies $A \cap B \in \mathscr P (S)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(A \in \mathscr P(S)$ AND $(B \in \mathscr P(S)$) implies $A \cap B \in \mathscr P (S)$ , with $\mathscr P$ being the powerset. If its still unclear, here is a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDKck.jpg.

I know what a powerset is, for example if we have A{Jack, John, Pete}, the powerset is {},{Jack},{John},{Pete},{Jack, John},{Jack, Pete},{John, Pete} and {Jack, John, Pete}. But i dont know what $\mathscr P$(S) is.

If we have A being {Jack, John} and B {John, Pete}, how would we then prove the statement?

Comment: Use that $\in\mathscr P(S)$ is the same as $\subseteq S$ (ans the "non-empty" condition is irrelevant).

Comment: By "A and B" do you mean A union B?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, well its very easy then. Our counterexample would be that A $\in$ S is all of A in S, same holds for be. Where as A union B $\in$ S would mean only what A and B have in common in S. But are we allowed to do that?

Comment: The picture you link mentions the intersection, but the implication would be true even if replaced with union.

Answer (score 0):

$A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq S$

So, $A \cap B$ is a subset of $S$ and since $\mathscr P(S)$ is a set that contains all of subsets of $S$ , $A \cap B$ is an element of $S$.